# how to convert php variable string to int

Tags: php, variables, integer

how to convert this string variable to integer

```
2, 990.00
```

I want to output this

```
2990.00
```

if i add two numbers like this

```
$num1 = '2, 990.00'; <br>
$num2 = '7, 990.00'; <br>

<br><br>

$ans = $num1 + $num2;<br>

echo $ans;
```

Answers is 9

Comment: Use str_replace() to eliminate the `, `

Answer (score 1):

`intval()` won't work with the string you have because of the comma. You can remove the comma by using `str_replace()` and then calling `intval()` like so:

`echo intval(str_replace(',', '', $myVal));`

and if you'd like to keep the decimal after:

`echo floatval(str_replace(',', '', $myVal));`

Comment: echo intval(str_replace(',','',$myVal));
this code is error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $subject)` to eliminate non-numeric characters.

Comment: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '*'

Comment: sorry dude i get the same result     2, 990.00

Answer (score 0):

```
$num1 = '2, 990.00';
$rep = array(',',' ');
$replace = array('','');
echo str_replace($rep,$replace,$num1);
```

Comment: or `echo str_replace(", ","",$num1);`